# Append data in excel using database

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have 2 classes

1)First used to generate an excel

2)To append data to same excel

But the problem is that i am able to generate the excel but i am unable to append data to it

i have a main class in which i check if file does not exist generate file and if it does append data to it

But when i try to append data it gives the following error

**Generationjava.io.IOException: Unable to read entire header; 0 bytes read; expected 512 bytes**

Can anyone please help!!!

Thanks in advance

```
  public void generateExcelFile() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
        try(  Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection( 
                   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" , 
                   "root" ,""
                );

                Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from table );
                   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("sample.xls"));
                )
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
        XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sample");
        XSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
        XSSFCell cell;
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("ID");
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("NAME");
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("ADDRESS");
        cell = row.createCell(3);

        int i = 1;

        while(resultSet.next()) {
           row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
           cell = row.createCell(0);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("id"));
           cell = row.createCell(1);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("name"));
           cell = row.createCell(2);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("address"));
           i++;
        }
        workbook.write(out);
       logger.info("Excel file generated!!");
     }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in Excel Generation");
        }
        }


    public void appendFile()   {
        try(  Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection( 
               "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" , 
               "root" ,""
            );

            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from table where date=some date after excel generation);//for eg

               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("sample.xls");
            )
    {

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("sample.xls");
     HSSFWorkbook workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook(input);

     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
     int lastrow= sheet.getLastRowNum();
     System.out.println("*********lastrow************"+lastrow);
     Row row = sheet.createRow(lastrow);
     Cell cell;
     int i = lastrow;

      while(resultSet.next()) {
           row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
           cell = row.createCell(lastrow);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("id"));
           cell = row.createCell(lastrow+1);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("name"));
           cell = row.createCell(lastrow+2);
           cell.setCellValue(resultSet.getString("address"));
           i++;
        }


     workbook1.write(out);
    logger.info("Excel file generated!!");
  }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in Excel Generation"+e);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need [Reading and Rewriting Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook), [get last row num](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getLastRowNum--) and then new creating rows after that last row num as you do it already.

Comment: Yes i tried it i cant get the result can u please show me

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question and show the code where you have tried opening an existing workbook and appending rows to it.

Comment: i have tired the code i edited above

Comment: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream error it is giving and i guess the logic is also different

Comment: Please provide the description of the problems using the code in your question and not in a comment. The question should be clear and now it is not. But if `Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(input);` throws that exception, then `input` is not an input stream from an proper Excel file. So your `exceldatabase.xlsx` is not a proper Excel file. Do creating it initially using Excel and having at least one worksheet in it.

Comment: i have edited my question above with all information @AxelRichter

Comment: Your `generateExcelFile` creates a `XSSFWorkbook` and saves it in a file `sample.xls`. This it should not do. A `XSSFWorkbook` is a workbook in Office Open XML format and should be named `*.xlsx` and not `*.xls`. Then your `appendFile` tries opening the `sample.xls` using `HSSFWorkbook` which expects a workbook in binary `BIFF` file format. But your `sample.xls` is not in that format. Why not using either `HSSFWorkbook` or `XSSFWorkbook` consistently? Why are you mixing both? As said they are totally different file formats.

Comment: which do u recommend?

Comment: There are pros and cons for both. But I clearly would prefer `XSSFWorkbook` (`*.xlsx` in Office Open XML format). This is newer and so it provides all new Excel extensions.

Comment: Doesnt work anyways thanks for the help!